# Почему дублируется автор коммита github?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Не могу понять, почему дважды показывается автор (я сам)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что в этом коммите у author и у committer указаны разные email'ы, например?

Comment: @andreymal а с чем это может быть связано и как это поправить?